# Cannot Instantiate abstract class but class is not abstract / derived method's param

Tags: c++, c++11

Why I can't create new instance of class which is derived class of my abstract base class? My derived class has overriden base method but with different parametr which is derived class of base class param.

```
class BaseArg {

} ;

class DerivedArg :public BaseArg{

} ;

class BaseHandler{
public:
virtual void handle(BaseArg* arg) = 0;
} ;

DerivedHandler {
void handle(DerivedArg* arg) {}
} ;


auto x = new DerivedHandler() ;
```

Compiler returns "Cannot Instantiate abstract class"

Why? In my opinion it should works.

Comment: covariance is applicable only to return types

Comment: `DerivedHandler {
void handle(DerivedArg* arg) {}
} ;` missing `struct` and probably inheritance.

Comment: `override` might help to spot this kind of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class BaseHandler
{
    public:
    virtual void handle(BaseArg* arg) = 0;
};
```

You declare a virtual function `handle` that needs to be able to accept *any* kind of `BaseArg`.

```
class DerivedHandler : public BaseHandler
{
public:
    void handle(DerivedArg* arg) { }
};
```

Your overriding function just accepts one specific type of `BaseArg`, so it does not suffice to provide an implementation for the (more general!) inherited function `handle`. The other way round would have worked (in theory only, see below) – or it would have (truely) worked with return type, as a `DerivedArg` returned always is a `BaseArg`, too...

For overview:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void f0(BaseArg* arg) = 0;
    virtual void f1(DerivedArg* arg) = 0;
    virtual BaseArg* f2() = 0;
    virtual DerivedArg* f3() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void f0(DerivedArg* arg) override; // FAILS!
    virtual void f1(BaseArg* arg) override;    // (fine...)(*)
    virtual DerivedArg* f2() override;         // fine...
    virtual BaseArg*    f3() override;         // FAILS!
};
```

(*) Actually, this case would have been fine *in theory*. C++, however, does not support contravariant function arguments, so this case will fail, too (the new function considered being an overload only)!

For more information, have a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Inheritance_in_object-oriented_languages).